# simple SQL query to Start and monitor the agent job in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

**(Query acquired from the link [Executing SQL Server Agent Job from a stored procedure and returning job result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249056/executing-sql-server-agent-job-from-a-stored-procedure-and-returning-job-result)  )**

What is the value of @time_constraint in the below code

```
WHILE @time_constraint = @ok        
    @time_constraint ?
    @ok?** Here @time_Constrain denotes???????
```

---

```
use msdb
-- Start job
DECLARE @job_name NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Demo_Test'
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = @job_name


-- Wait for job to finish
DECLARE @job_history_id AS INT = NULL

WHILE @time_constraint = @ok
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @job_history_id = activity.job_history_id
    FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs jobs
    INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity activity ON activity.job_id = jobs.job_id
    WHERE jobs.name = @job_name
    ORDER BY activity.start_execution_date DESC

    IF @job_history_id IS NULL
    BEGIN
        WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'
        CONTINUE
    END
    ELSE
        BREAK
END


-- Check exit code
SELECT history.run_status
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory history
WHERE history.instance_id = @job_history_id
```

Comment: Its your code - how do you expect us to know how it works?

Comment: If by chance you have "acquired" the code from elsewhere you need to acknowledge that as a reference.

Comment: Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249056/executing-sql-server-agent-job-from-a-stored-procedure-and-returning-job-result

Comment: By lapponiandevil

Comment: No idea what @timeconstraint is. It was clearly only a code snippet, not the whole code. It's just a variable, nothing special.

Comment: Its the complete code. yes its the variable. My question is what value is assigned to that variable @timeconstraint

Comment: Its not complete code, its pseudo-code, and as best I can tell its just saying "put your own condition in here to make sure the loop doesn't wait forever". However you could ask the author directly by adding a comment to their answer and tagging their name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Full reference is below, and the clue is in the comment

**"You might want to put in some checks for how long the WHILE-loop is allowed to run. I chose to keep that part out of the example."**

As stated in comments, you are supposed to insert a check to stop the code from running forever, for example:

```
DECLARE @time_constraint datetime 
DECLARE @ok datetime

SET @time_constraint = DATEADD(second, 5, GETDATE()) -- Run for 5 seconds 
SET @ok = GETDATE()

SELECT @time_constraint as future, @ok as [current]

WHILE @time_constraint > @ok BEGIN      
   SELECT @ok = GETDATE() 
END
```

> For all you guys who are not allowed to use the OPENROWSET command,
>   this might help. I found the start for my solution here:
>
> http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/89659729-fea8-4df0-8057-79e0a437b658/dynamically-checking-job-status-with-tsql
>
> This relies on the fact that some columns of the
>   msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity table first get populated after the job
>   finishes in one way or the other.
>
> ```
> -- Start job
> DECLARE @job_name NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'JobName'
> EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = @job_name
>
>
> -- Wait for job to finish
> DECLARE @job_history_id AS INT = NULL
>
> WHILE @time_constraint = @ok
> BEGIN
>     SELECT TOP 1 @job_history_id = activity.job_history_id
>     FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs jobs
>     INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity activity ON activity.job_id = jobs.job_id
>     WHERE jobs.name = @job_name
>     ORDER BY activity.start_execution_date DESC
>
>     IF @job_history_id IS NULL
>     BEGIN
>         WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'
>         CONTINUE
>     END
>     ELSE
>         BREAK
> END
>
>
> -- Check exit code
> SELECT history.run_status
> FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory history
> WHERE history.instance_id = @job_history_id
> ```
>
> You might want to put in some checks for how long the WHILE-loop is
>   allowed to run. I chose to keep that part out of the example.
>
> Microsoft guidance for exit codes etc.:
>   http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174997.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The loop checks where there is a record on the job history. If there is, it breaks the loop, if it doesn't then it keeps on waiting using `WAITFOR`. Since waiting forever might be a bad idea, there should be an additional time-constrained condition. This is what the writer meant with `@time_constraint = @ok`, although the names aren't the best.

For example:

```
DECLARE @MaxWaitingTimeInMinutes INT = 5

DECLARE @StartTime DATETIME = GETDATE()

WHILE DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @StartTime, GETDATE()) <= @MaxWaitingTimeInMinutes
BEGIN

    -- Check for job's history. Break if exists, wait if not.

END
```

Another example:

```
DECLARE @WaitUntil DATETIME = DATEADD(MINUTE, 5, GETDATE())

WHILE GETDATE() <= @WaitUntil
BEGIN

    -- Check for job's history. Break if exists, wait if not.

END
```