SQL Server agent job steps with dependency
I have a SQL Server agent parent job in which the 1st step is to execute 4 different child jobs 1, 2, 3, 4 and the 2nd step is to execute another job child job 5, after starting the child job 1, how to wait until child job 4 is successfully completed before moving on to the 2nd step which is to execute child job 5?
Query:
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name=N'child_job_1'; EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name=N'child_job_2'; EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name=N'child_job_3'; EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name=N'child_job_4'

All these jobs are run concurrently. Now the step where I'm stuck with is each time when the 1st job step is run each of the 4 jobs take their own time to complete and it's hard to tell which would complete first. Wait until all 4 jobs successfully complete, then execute 2nd step of the parent job. How would I check on this and proceed with the execution of 2nd step?

Try to look here how to get current state of job and handle it in your procedure:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249056/executing-sql-server-agent-job-from-a-stored-procedure-and-returning-job-result
